# R Shiny data table images not updating when running in browser

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm creating a Shiny app which displays images and text in a data table. This table will need to update depending on the user's input. When I run the app in a window the table updates as expected. However, when I run it in a browser the text updates but the image does not. How do I make it work in a browser?

EDIT: For clarity, the below example is just to reproduce the issue. The real app could display any number of different pictures, which aren't saved locally until the user makes a selection (they're pulled from a database). I was hoping to avoid having different filenames because I could potentially end up with hundreds of thousands of pictures saved locally, but if that's the only solution then I will have to cleanup the folder periodically

**Reproducible example (requires 2 local images)**

```
library(shiny)
library(imager)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Tables to export"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("pic1","Pic1"),
      actionButton("pic2","Pic2")
    ),

    # Show tables
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        dataTableOutput('tab1')
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$pic1, {
    pic <- load.image("www/pic1.png")
    save.image(pic,"www/picToShow.png")

    tab1 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"='<img src="picToShow.png" width=150 height=100>',x1=1,x2=2,x3=3,row.names="p1")), 
                      escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20))
    output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(tab1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$pic2, {
    pic <- load.image("www/pic2.png")
    save.image(pic,"www/picToShow.png")

    tab1 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"='<img src="picToShow.png" width=150 height=100>',x1=4,x2=5,x3=6,row.names="p1")), 
                      escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20))
    output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(tab1)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

*Expected behaviour (behaviour in window)*

[image: Expected behaviour (behaviour in a window)]

*Behaviour in the browser*

[image: Behaviour in browser]

Comment: Well, since you write them both to the same file name "picToShow.png" your browser assumes they are the same file and uses the cached version. It would be better NOT to use the same file name. Just use either "pic1.png" or "pic2.png" as the `src=` in the image tag. Otherwise you'd have to write some javascript to trick your browser into reloading an image it thinks it already loaded.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. Okay thanks, I'll see if I can make it work with different filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @MrFlick's comment. Why do you load both images and resave them with the same name? The browser will think that it knows the image already and will re-use the already loaded image.

Why not just include `pic1.png` and `pic2.png` directly?

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$pic1, {
    tab1 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"='<img src="pic1.png" width=150 height=100>',x1=1,x2=2,x3=3,row.names="p1")),
                      escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20))
    output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(tab1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$pic2, {
    tab1 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"='<img src="pic2.png" width=150 height=100>',x1=4,x2=5,x3=6,row.names="p1")),
                      escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20))
    output$tab1 <- renderDataTable(tab1)
  })
}
```

Comment: My actual app could have hundreds of thousands of different images to choose from (the image gets downloaded when the user makes a selection), so I wanted to avoid having a folder containing too many image files by having the existing images replaced

Comment: But this way, you waste useful time / ressources on loading and resaving the image in the server function.

Comment: That was just to make my code reproducible. The images don't exist until the user makes a selection. When they make a selection, a database is called and a picture is saved locally. That picture is then displayed in a data table. If the user makes a different selection, a new picture replaces it (to avoid having 500,000 images saved locally).

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. Than I would still save the image with a unique hash in a certain folder and save the name in a `reactiveValue` (similar to @DSGym's approach). To prevent having more than 1 image at a time in that folder, you could empty the directory before saving a new image.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(shiny)
library(imager)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Tables to export"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("pic1","Pic1"),
            actionButton("pic2","Pic2")
        ),

        # Show tables
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                DT::dataTableOutput('tab1')
            )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

    vals = reactiveValues(pic1 = 0, pic2 = 0)

    observeEvent(input$pic1, {
        vals$pic1 <- 1
        vals$pic2 <- 0
    })

    observeEvent(input$pic2, {
        print(vals$pic1)
        print(vals$pic2)
        vals$pic1 <- 0
        vals$pic2 <- 1
    })

    dynamicdf <- reactive({

        if(vals$pic1 == 1) {
            df <- data.frame(
                pic = c('<img src="http://flaglane.com/download/american-flag/american-flag-large.png" height="52"></img>'),
                x1 = c(1),
                x2 = c(2),
                x3 = c(3)
            )
        } else {
            df <- data.frame(
                pic = c('<img src="img2.jpg" width=150 height=100></img>'),
                x1 = c(4),
                x2 = c(5),
                x3 = c(6)
            )
        }
        print(df)
        return(df)
    })

    output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(dynamicdf(), escape = FALSE)
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In Shiny Apps you do not load or saves images. You display them by using a path to the folder, where your pictures are stored. This can be a Link on the internet or a path on your machine.

Do it like this. I use a `reactiveValue` to track the last click of your button. This is a good solution if you have a large number of pictures you may want to render. (I adopted that style from the modern JS Library ReactJS) Based on the state you display your pictures. Do **NOT** use the `www` path, this is already expected by shiny. Leave it as in the example2 in the App.

For me it also only worked with the `escape = FALSE` parameter in the App. Try that if it does not work without it.